# How to find the second smallest/biggest number from a user input using python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to python, tried to complete a task which requires to find a summ of two biggest and two smallest numbers which were inputted by the user, the number 0 means the input is over, couldn't figure out why the code doesn't work

```
b = 0
c = 0
b2 = 0
c2 = 0
for i in range(-30000, 30000):
    a = int(input())
    if a == 0:
        break
    elif a > b:
        b = a
    elif a < c:
        c = a
    elif a >= b-1:
        b2 = a
    elif a <= c+1:
        c2 = a
print(b, b2, c, c2)
summ1 = b + b2
summ2 = c + c2
print(summ1, summ2)
```

b - biggest number, c - smallest number, b2 - second biggest number, c2 - second smallest number

After inputting the numbers and running the code the variables b2 and c2 are always 0, the biggest and smallest numbers work though

Comment: `a >= b-1` is not a condition that the second-biggest number will satisfy. What if the numbers I enter are `1, 4, 9, 12, 42, 40, 3`? Step through your code with this example input and see how it will behave.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a value is larger than `b`, you don't only have to set the new `b` but also move the old `b` to `b2`:

```
    elif a > b:
        b, b2 = a, b
     
    elif a < c:
        c, c2 = a, c

    elif a >= b2:
        b2 = a
    elif a <= c2:
        c2 = a
```

The remaining `elif` statements were wrong. The number has to be higher than `b2` or smaller than `c2`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to learn Python here, so let me give you some general tips on how to solve your problem more simply:

1. First, collect all of the user input into a Python list
2. Now, find the largest 2 and smallest 2 numbers in that list.  Remember that python has `max()` and `min()` functions.
3. Do the summing and printing

One quick python tip:  Your `for i in range(-30000, 30000):` is really a "for forever:"  In Python, we do that with `while True:`

Comment: You could also sort the list. Then the smallest items will be at index 0 and 1, and the largest will be at index -1 and -2.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Scratched the previous code and created a new one using a list and `lst.sort()`, it's a way better way of doing this.